# How to delete unix user mail in /var/spool/mail/user without root using a script?

Tags: unix

With root access you can just delete the file but will get permission denied if you are just a regular user. How could one delete their mail in this case with a script?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any posts about this on SO currently.

```
echo 'd *' | mail -N
```

Will work.